# How do I find good minerals in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

How far do I need to dig to find good minerals and materials for good items?
I think I've been digging for almost 200 blocks now and all I find is copper, iron, silver and gold. Where do I find good minerals like amethyst and such, to make lightsabers?

Comment: I guess it's just very lucky..Coe in his new Coe's Bane LP found an amethyst vein and a demon altar thing about 10 blocks down.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are only a few rules to the spawning of ores and minerals and so far elevation really is not coming into play.

- Ore (Copper, Iron, Silver, Gold) can appear anywhere. Silver and Gold are very common on floating islands
- Gems only seem appear in stone (I've yet to see any cluster of minerals in dirt alone)
- Hellstone is found, oddly enough, in hell. (Could be considered elevation restriction)
- Metorite comes from meteors
- Demonite comes from Demons (Bosses). Very small (2-4 blocks) groups can be found anywhere underground. Larger groups of Demonite can be found in the Corruption

Elevations do not seem to matter. I have found everything from copper to gold directly on or 1-2 layers of dirt below the surface of the map (not depth level 0, but the actual surface). I have also found minerals in stone outcroppings near the surface (Yet to find one actually on the surface but still above 0 depth according to a depth meter). It should be noted that all the minerals I have come across so far are on the edge of the stone veins, so I am not suggesting coring through the middle of a large collection of stone looking for them.

### 1.1 Update

I am glad that Raven Dreamer commented as it gives me a point to comment on. The new 1.1 generation does seem to give depth an impact on ore generation now. I have only played on a handful of new worlds so far so do not feel I can overall change the information above but I have noticed that the size of the deposits of silver and gold appear more often and in larger quantities when I delve further down. And yes, a floating island is a good place to get a nice collection of ores! :)

Comment: I noticed that minerals like silver and gold seems more frequent near water. Is just an impression?

Comment: I have not yet been given that impression about silver and gold.. But water is fairly abundant within the world I am currently strip-mining.. erm.. excavating in a nature friendly way :)

Comment: I strongly suspect that elevation does come into play. I've noticed that large silver and moderate gold strikes are somewhat more common when deep into the stone layer. (I've never seen a really large gold strike.)

Comment: I'll add that Floating Islands are pretty much resplendent with gold and silver ore. Easy pickin' if you can find one.

Comment: Gold IS remarkably common close to Lava.  Frustratingly so, in fact.  You'll find a nice patch of fresh gold ore, right underneath a huge pool of lava.  Though this is probably because there are lots of lava pools at the same level that Gold Ore is common.

Comment: @Zibbobz With 1.2, and golds possible replacement of Platinum.. I have to say I find platinum all over the place again. I do seem to have better luck if I go down a bit but no where near lava layer. I also find it quite often just down in the jungle.

Answer (score 6):

One simple answer: [Spelunker Potion](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Spelunker_Potion).

Make as many as you can (sadly they require gold, but a couple of pieces of gold ore will do the trick to start). Go down to the Rock layer, fire up a spelunker potion and away you go. Make sure to go for Gold ore first, since you'll need more of that to make more Spelunker potions. If you need Moonglow, go to the surface jungle, grab some at night and [then farm it in clay pots](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/terraria-herb-farm.34349/).

Answer (score 3):

> This may ruin your gaming experience. You may no longer be excited when you discover something.

You can try looking at the whole map using [MoreTerra](http://moreterra.codeplex.com/).

[image]

It reads the map binary file. [Instructions](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/terraria-map-viewer.4226/) for using MoreTerra are on the Terraria Forum.

Unfortunately, out of the natural resources, it only shows Amethyst, Diamond, Emerald, Ruby, Sapphire and Topaz.

---

If you're feeling really frustrated trying to find ore, try making a Small World. The ores, chests and terrain layers are scaled to be closer together. Build up your items in the small world and then start your adventure.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen any hard evidence for which layers have which types of materials yet but after recently breaking into the cavern layer (starting at -850ft) I've been finding quite a few more gemstone veins.

You'll know you've reached the cavern layer because the background turns from brown to grey. Just keep digging!

Comment: It always seemed to me that while they can appear at any depth, you're a lot more likely to find Silver and Gold in larger deposits once you get to caverns. The gemstones also seem to be more prevalent down there too.

Answer (score 0):

Using [TerraFirma](http://seancode.com/terrafirma/), I made a few screenshots of Copper, Iron, Silver, and Gold Ore placement on a fresh small map.

You can tell that in general, this stuff is found anywhere, the Silver and Gold, are less likely above ground and are found mostly down in the "Underground" layer (where the background changes to the rocky stuff)

### Copper

[image: Copper]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/f8b01abce8f5e99e58c2c902870704d3.png))</sub>

### Iron

[image: Iron]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/e14991fa9f78004e04a04f53629562c3.png))</sub>

### Silver

[image: Silver]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/c75cdc95d7011d53e1dfa5ea5d41c5dd.png))</sub>

### Gold

[image: Gold]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/2e3eae294a2709723515ed42224ddbc7.png))</sub>

## Hard mode ores

The hard mode ores are definitely based on elevation.  Adamantite only shows up around and below the "lava line", while Mythril can spawn a bit higher, and Cobalt pretty much anywhere underground.

Answer (score 0):

Gemstones, such as Amethyst, which are used to make various Phasesabers (Lightsabers), are particularly rare and less obvious than regular ores.  You will find them speckled in dirt and stone(?) as multi-colored specks, sometimes near ore deposits, but sometimes not.  There really isn't any good way to hunt them down besides using a Spelunker Potion, just make sure you light up every cave pocket and check every wall for tell-tale discolorations in the walls, floors and ceilings.

Demonite comes from defeating bosses, which means going to the Corruption (Crimson in newer worlds as well) and breaking open Demon Orbs (Hearts in Crimson) to fight Eater of Worlds (or Brian of Cthulhu).  Eye of Cthulhu will also grant you some Demonite, but you will also need Shadow Scale for better Demonite items, for which you'll need to fight Eater of Worlds, possibly multiple times.

Hellstone is in hell, aaaaall the way at the bottom of the map.  Build yourself a Hellevator for better transport to this area, as this is where some of the best equipment resides.

[See this question for how to build a Hellevator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132996/efficient-hellevator-design)